# Schedule timer to be executed once a month - C#

Tags: c#, timer, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, scheduler

I need to transfer some data from SQL Server to MySQL, once a month. I have already done this transfer stuff, but I don't know (and I have not found out on the internet) how to set a timer that executes this transfer a specific day every month. I don't want just to set a timer interval in milliseconds because the number of days vary from one month to another.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: :/ http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=11400 scheduling sql server jobs -- first result on google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Windows Task Scheduler for this kind of work. Look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for command line options of `Schtasks` (there's tons of them)

Example 1:

> To schedule a task that runs on the first day of every month
>
> The following command schedules the MyApp program to run on the first
>   day of every month. Because a value of 1 is the default for both the
>   /mo (modifier) parameter and the /d (day) parameter, these parameters
>   are omitted from the command.

```
schtasks /create /tn "My App" /tr myapp.exe /sc monthly
```

Example 2:

> To schedule a task for the 15th day
>
> The following command schedules the MyApp program to run on 15th of
>   every month at 3:00 P.M. (15:00). It uses the /d parameter to specify
>   the date. It also uses the /st parameter to specify the start time.

```
schtasks /create /tn "My App" /tr myapp.exe /sc monthly /d 15 /st 15:00
```

Comment: That's what I need! could you please specify all the the parameters as if I wanted to run the program every 28th (or any day)? just for testing purposses...

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like something you should set-up as a scheduled task or a SQL server job rather than having a process run for a month via a timer?

Links:

- [SQL Server job in 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- [Schedule windows task](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Working-Windows-Server-2008-Task-Scheduler-Part1.html)

I guess you could also setup a task as a windows service and check the last time you did the update via a setting in the database, but that seems like overkill. From the sound of it you already have a C# app setup that does the job, so I would just make a scheduled windows task.

Comment: I prefer not to do it by a SQL server job, I'll take a look at the 2nd article, I think it could solve my issue.

Comment: I think would work best for you. SQL server jobs are really good though, we use them all the time for a variety of tasks, so I would encourage becoming familiar with them.